# Powershell - Remove multiple AD members from multiple AD groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a regular need to remove multiple different users from multiple different groups, and thus far have been using dsmod command scripts to get it done. However, I've been trying to work some powershell magic to upgrade, and perhaps quicken the process. I also need the script to output a log of actions, either success and failure together or separately.

The input file that I'm using is a .csv with the userid in the first column and the group name in the second. The test input file that I'm working with has both the distinguishedname and simply the samaccountname represented so that I could see how it would accept input. Also, just so we're on the same page I've edited the output errors to protect our domain information, but trust that what is there is a fair representation of what it should be.

So far I've found a few variations that I've tried. The first is:

```
$fileList = import-CSV -Delimiter ',' c:\temp\Logs\RemoveUserInput.csv 

foreach($entry in $fileList)            
{ 
  $user = $entry.UserID 
  $group = $entry.Group
  remove-adgroupmember -Identity $group -Member $user -Confirm:$false
}
```

And the error that I'm getting is:

```
PS C:\Temp\Logs> .\remove_users_from_group.ps1
remove-adgroupmember : Cannot find an object with identity:
'cn=user1,dc=domain,dc=com' under:
'DC=domain,DC=com'.
At C:\Temp\Logs\remove_users_from_group.ps1:7 char:3
+   remove-adgroupmember -Identity $group -Member $user -Confirm:$false
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cn=user1,dc=domain,dc=c
   om:ADPrincipal) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Micros
   oft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember

remove-adgroupmember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'user1' under:
'DC=domain,DC=com'.
At C:\Temp\Logs\remove_users_from_group.ps1:7 char:3
+   remove-adgroupmember -Identity $group -Member $user -Confirm:$false
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (user1:ADPrincipal) [Remove-ADG
   roupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Micros
   oft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

A colleague provided a variation on the script, suggesting that part of the issue might lay with our multiple domain forest, and removing users from domain1 from a group in domain2. The script variation is as follows:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$FileList = Import-CSV -Delimiter ',' C:\temp\Logs\RemoveUserInput.csv 

# Create new ADSearcher Object – could also be done differently
$objForest = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$ForestDefaultNC = "DC="+$objForest.RootDomain.Name.Replace(".",",DC=")
$ADSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ADSearcher.PageSize = 1000

foreach($entry in $FileList) {
    $UserName = $entry.UserID 
    $GroupName = $entry.Group

    $GroupFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(Name=$GroupName))"
    $ADSearcher.Filter = $GroupFilter
    $ADSearcher.SearchRoot = New-Object ADSI("GC://$($ForestDefaultNC)")
    $Group = $ADSearcher.FindAll()

    $UserFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(Name=$UserName))"
    $ADSearcher.Filter = $UserFilter
    $ADSearcher.SearchRoot = New-Object ADSI("GC://$($ForestDefaultNC)")
    $User = $ADSearcher.FindAll()

    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User
}
```

And then the error that follows is:

```
PS C:\Temp\Logs> .\2remove_users_from_group.ps1
Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the
"System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection" value of type
"System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection" to type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup".
At C:\Temp\Logs\2remove_users_from_group.ps1:28 char:36
+     Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User
+                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-ADGroupMember], Par
   ameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveD
   irectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember

Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the
"System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection" value of type
"System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection" to type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup".
At C:\Temp\Logs\2remove_users_from_group.ps1:28 char:36
+     Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User
+                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-ADGroupMember], Par
   ameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveD
   irectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

Any assistance that can be provided would be appreciated.

Edit: As requested, below is an example of the .csv file:

Its very simple, and probably exactly as you imagine:

```
UserID,group
"cn=user1,dc=domain,dc=com","cn=group1,dc=domain,dc=com"
user1,group1
```

Comment: What does your csv look like (I have a good guess)? Show us a couple of lines?

Comment: And you are sure those DNs are correct? Are the user and group placed in the root of the domain? Not a usual scenario...

Comment: Like I said in the question, I've changed the DNs for what you're seeing here for example purposes only. However, I am 100% sure that the information in the actual file I am using is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Result of FindAll() method is SearchResultCollection type as it can contain multiple users.

For use in Remove-ADGroupMember you need to get the directory entry or pass some attribute like distinguished name.

Identity can be one of following according to [MS Docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617242.aspx):

> You can identify a group by its distinguished name (DN), GUID, security identifier (SID), or Security Accounts Manager (SAM) account name.

so for example:

```
$GroupDN = ($ADSearcher.FindAll() | select -first 1).Properties.distinguishedname

$UserDN = ($ADSearcher.FindAll() | select -first 1).Properties.distinguishedname
```

But if you already have DNs in the input CSV and you don't want to explicitly check if the group/user exists you can just call Remove-ADGroupMember with the DNs and catch errors if the object does not exist.